# VBA move selected range up / down (with offset?)

Tags: excel, vba, range, move, offset

I am building a tool where user-selected cell contents is moved around with arrow shapes.

The code below works great to move 1 or more group of adjacent cells down.
However, reversing the code seems tricky (+1 in offset does not work :-?)

Any idea?
Thank you, 
Augustin

```
Sub Move_Up()
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Comment: is your intent to drag cells around only or do you need to shift overwritten ones?

Comment: Use `1`, not `+1` - `.Offset` needs a ***number*** not a description of the operation.

Comment: @Comintern, it's not that: `+1` would be immediately converted to `1` in the VBA IDE and the issue would still remain. Should Augustin answer my question it could be possible to find the way out

Comment: To clarify the initial request, the goal was to shift / drag cells around without overwriting destination cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

supposing cells are to be moved around and overwritten ones are just shifted where moved ones once were, the code could be the following:

```
Sub MoveUp()
    Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Rows(1).Offset(-1).Cut Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.count + 1)
    Selection.Rows(1).Offset(-1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.Offset(-1).Select
End Sub

Sub MoveDown()
    Selection.Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.count).Offset(2).Cut Selection.Rows(1)
    Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.count).Offset(2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a `Selected` block of cells **up** by one row then:

```
Sub ShiftBlockUp()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
    Intersect(r(1).EntireRow, r).Offset(-1, 0).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

If you want to move a `Selected` block of cells **down** by one row then:

```
Sub ShiftBlockDown()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
    Intersect(r(1).EntireRow, r).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Comment: the same all functionality of your `ShiftBlockDown()` would be given by `Selection.Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Comment: These ShiftBlockDown() and ShiftBlockUp() lines lead to data deletion